# Get the path to the current application in node-webkit

Tags: node-webkit

In node-webkit, is there any way to find the path to the current application? In node.js, you can use `__dirname` to find the path to the current application, but in node-webkit, the variable `__dirname` appears to be undefined.

The following node.js script prints the file path correctly:

`console.log(__dirname)`

The following node-webkit script does not print the file path correctly:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    alert(__dirname);
</script>
```

What is the correct way to find the path to the current application in node-webkit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to this question was discussed here: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/node-webkit/IwGzluFC9iU/discussion

> On Windows, use "process.execPath" to see the path of the executable that launched it. Then work from there, removing the executable's filename from the path to get the folder's path (assuming your app's .nw is relative to the executable or is combined with it).
>
> This works for me whether it is running with the zipped 'app.nw' or where 'nw.exe' and 'app.nw' are combined into one executable file (app.exe).

Comment: Could you please copy a summary of the solution. Link only answers tend to lose all value once the external resource goes poof.

Comment: In the discussion mentioned in this answer using `window.location` for obtaining the path was suggested. If the node-webkit app was ran from a `nw` file, the path will be a temp one (the one to which node-webkit extracted the `nw` file).

Comment: Doesn't work if main is an external Uri or navigation has occured away from your root folder.

Comment: The mailing list is removed. Please update or remove your link.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer's link is no longer available, so here is a short answer:

nw.js extract the content of your app, to a temp directory, every time you run it.

If you want to access the path where nw.js extracted your app, use `process.cwd()`

In other causes, where you want to access the path of your executable app, use:

```
var path = require('path');
var nwDir = path.dirname(process.execPath);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the path to the App source (i.e. the folder that contains `package.json`) then you can use `process.cwd()`.

No matter what the environment's true working directory is when the node executable is launched, it will set `process.cwd()` to the location of the App source.  If the App is contained in an archive, cwd will point to the **temporary folder** where the source is extracted.

Importantly, note that `process.cwd()` can be changed during the application run by `process.chdir(newPath)` and potentially by other events as well, so you might want to store the initial value at application launch.

**EDIT:**
Just to clarify, `process.cwd()` is set to the folder that contains the actual `package.json` file that is used by the running app. So if you have packaged your app in an archive or executable (zip, exe, nwz, nw, etc), then nw.exe will **extract** the project files to a temporary directory before running the app. So `process.cwd()` will point to that temporary folder, **not** the location of the original archive or executable.

Comment: That's the one I needed and also probably ideal for flexibility.

Comment: Actually that didn't work. I'm trying to package by merging app.nw with nw.exe and absolutely nothing I've tried will give me the root of the app. In my case I need to reference an SQLite db that's two directories up.

Comment: Erik, what do you mean the "root of the app". The method I posted above specifically gives the location of the **extracted** files--NOT the location of the exe (or .zip, .nw, .nwz, etc).  If the app is packaged as a zip or exe, then it will probably be extracted to a temporary folder (as I mentioned above).

Comment: Sorry, I can't even remember what I was doing wrong now. It seemed like I couldn't access the DB from directories above the .exe but I think I was packaging incorrectly. Doubling up on the exe somehow IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
var nw = require('nw.gui'); //This line is only required for NW.js 0.12.x and below

console.log(nw.__dirname)
```

Answer (score 0):

window.location won't work if you're loaded an external uri, but the following seems reliable regardless:

```
var path = require('path');
,appPath = path.dirname(require.main.filename)
```

Comment: I tried this and found that `require.main` is undefined. This is because `require` is redefined by node-webkit so that `require("nw.gui")` gets special treatment. What you want to use is `global.require.main.filename`.

Comment: In my case that doesn't work either. I'm trying to reference something two directories up from a package that merged nw.exe with app.nw.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure when this is added, but I believe the official way to get the start up path now is:

```
nw.App.startPath
```