# how can I access local resources that are not zipped into nw package in nw.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-applications, nw.js

Building web app in nwjs make unavailable to access files that are located in program directory (together with app.nw file) and it's not good idea to add all files into nw package because some files may need  to changed by IO at run time. Structure will be as follow

-app.nw
   -data.json

How can I access files outside of nw package in nw.js

Answer (score 1):

You can use the node file system module to read files across the file system. Here's the docs: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html.

If you're just reading JSON files, you can simply require them like you would a module, for example:

```
require('path/to/file.json')
```

Comment: if app is generated as portable file, path of app is dynamic.

Comment: I don't think there's a perfect solution for that. You could use an installer to place files where you expect them. You could also have the user provide the path to the file if it can't be found. If you use HTML5 file inputs, nw will use the operating system's native file dialogs and will read the file in as a blob.

Comment: Thanks alot I found solution from here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783542/get-the-path-to-the-current-application-in-node-webkit) 
It needs to get directory of executable path as the nw package is bundled with nw.exe. logic is: `var path = require('path');
var nwDir = path.dirname(process.execPath);`